# What is the 'malty' flavour added to tea to make it taste like biscuits?

Tags: tea

I'm in Australia - and for my birthday I ordered some British tea - [Yorkshire Toast and Jam](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Yorkshire-Tea-Toast-Flavoured-total/dp/B08LDDBTV1). (Picture below.) Which was really nice, but at about 80c per bag, a little hard to justify.

I gave some to my wife and she said:

> "That's just Berry flavoured tea added to normal tea"

That shattered my illusions a little bit, but then I got practical. I started mixing strawberry flavoured teas and [English Breakfast tea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/English_breakfast_tea) to get that "toast and jam" taste. For the cost, it was pretty close, and I'll probably order some for my birthday next year.

My wife likes their other product - [Yorkshire tea 'Malty Biscuit'](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07BWDLPMT).

So I thought to myself "I can engineer this one too!" But then I was dumbfounded. Short of breaking up actual malt biscuits to attempt to mix them with tea (leading to a crumby tea problem), how would you do this?

Now I imagine you can try adding some kind of original [malt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malt) ingredient to it. But again you end up at the 'crumby tea' problem.

When I look at the ingredients list of both they just say "tea, flavouring".

My question is: **What is the 'malty' flavour added to tea to make it taste like biscuits?**

[image]

Comment: It could be just about anything that's toasted.  In latin markets, you can get coconut water drinks with toasted coconut in it, and it really reminds me of the flavor of breakfast cereal, even though there are no grains in it.  You could also toast some wheat berries or similar and steep that to see what flavors you get out of it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not something I've ever tried, but I'd be tempted towards either the bottled malt drinks popular in the Caribbean (eg [Supermalt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supermalt)), or [Horlicks](https://www.horlicks.co.uk).

Or, you can just buy "malt flavour" - Random google search  for liquid flavour manufacturers - http://www.weberflavors.com/products/liquid-flavors/

Perhaps your 'crumby' malt could be done as a separate infusion first, then just the liquid transferred to the tea.

btw, those tea-bags are about £1.50 in the UK - you could probably find a cheaper supplier than Amazon US ;)

Comment: There's also malt extract and malt syrup (similar but not quite the same, I think), which are widely available in the UK at least.  They have a sweetening effect so you'd want to reduce any sugar you add

Comment: Yeah, health food shops always seem to stock a lot of that kind of thing. Not the kind of places I frequent, as I'm very very dubious of their claims that I can buy specific "health" in a bottle ;))

Comment: I was thinking more of the home baking section of the supermarket, which is my natural habitat. [e.g. Asda](https://groceries.asda.com/product/stock/meridian-barley-malt-extract/910001471627)

Comment: Ah, never thought of that. You can tell I don't bake much, can't you ;) Looks like malty marmite.

Comment: Ovaltine is another malt mix that's similar and could also work.

Comment: In the Winnie-The-Pooh books, Roo and Tiggr both ate extract-of-malt sandwiches. I'm not sure why I mention this.

Comment: @ChrisH I use malt extract instead of sugar in wholemeal bread, because I like the flavour.  I've found that no supermarket sells it, and even the wholefoods shops (e.g. Holland and Barrett) around here don't have it.  As with most things though, you can order it very easily from Amazon.  I buy Potters - presumably there are other producers, but this is cheap and tastes good.  You're also going to need milk in the tea, of course.

Comment: @Graham strange that I found an Asda link, but Sainsbury's don't do it.  Another use is in beer making, so if you've got a homebrew shop near you, they probably have it.  I've made beer from kits that use a couple of litres of syrupy malt extract, but the dried stuff is probably more useful

Comment: @ChrisH True, but homebrew shops tend to sell it by the litre, which is a bit more than you need for a cup of tea. :)

Comment: @Graham I was thinking of the 500g bags of dried, comparable to a bag of sugar

Answer (score 3):

Here's an ingredient list I found for English Malted Biscuits online:

> Fortified Wheat Flour (wheat flour, calcium carbonate, iron,
> nicotinamide, thiamin), Vegetable Oil (palm and rapeseed [in varying
> proportions]), Sugar, Barley Malt Extract, Wheat Starch, Milk Powder,
> Raising Agents (sodium hydrogen carbonate, ammonium hydrogen
> carbonate), Salt, Flavorings.

Which confirms that Barley Malt Extract is a key ingredient. Yes and the insidious "Flavorings" conspires to thwart us. But why not try Malt first and see if that's evocative enough? In searching the Web, I found that there are brands of Malt-based sweeteners, which sounds perfect for tea. The other major source would be supplies for beer brewers, though I'd worry that they might be extremely concentrated or might not be flavorful raw.

Answer (score -1):

Try adding cardamom powder. It's used in quite a few teas and biscuits. Add about half a teaspoon to one teaspoon for one cup.

Comment: OP wanted malt, not cardamom. Presumably if he'd wanted cardamom, that's what he'd have asked for,

Comment: In fairness to this answer, flavors are notoriously hard for us laymen to describe with specificity and there are many flavor/odor associations and if cardamom is in fact used commonly in malted biscuits -- I'm a yank and don't know -- this could be a useful step in making the tea taste like a malted biscuit. Especially since cardamom is a proven "not crumbly" ingredient in teas.